# Drag Drop Handling from Thunderbird

Tags: email, drag-and-drop, thunderbird

Has anyone ever handled a drag drop of emails from thunderbird? any references links code?

I want to be able to drag emails from thunderbird to my application?

Comment: It would be great to have a generic "thunderbird drag&dropper" extension that has a configurable restful backend so that each drag&drop would notify an URL that can handle the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like it isn't possible. Although I can't seem to find any actual documentation, here is what my experimentation has found so far.

Thunderbird provides drop data with the following MIME types, when tested against an IMAP server:

- `text/x-moz-message` - UTF-16 encoded URL that looks like `imap-message://user@server/FOLDER#ID`
- `text/x-moz-url` - UTF-16 encoded URL that looks like `imap://user@server:port/fetch%3EUID%3E/FOLDER%3EID`
- `text/uri-list` - ASCII (?) URL that looks like `imap://user@host:port/fetch%3EUID%3E/FOLDER%3EID"`
- `_NETSCAPE_URL` - ASCII (?) URL that looks like `imap://user@host:port/fetch%3EUID%3E/FOLDER%3EID`
- `application/x-moz-file-promise-url` - UTF-16 encoded URL that looks like `imap://user@host:port/fetch%3EUID%3E/FOLDER%3EID?fileName=SUBJECT.eml`
- `application/x-moz-file-promise` - Empty

Comment: As a hopefully quick aside, what tool did you use to view the drop data?

Answer (score 4):

The relevant Thunderbird code is [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/msgMail3PaneWindow.js), but AFAICS it is not finished... What I did was writing a Thunderbird extension that overrides the `draggesture` event of `#threadTree treechildren` and calls a slightly modified version of `ThreadPaneOnDragStart` that writes the dragged message somewhere inside the temp directory (using `SaveMessageToDisk`), returning the file name as `application/x-moz-file-promise` (or whatever you'd like to catch inside your application).

This has two drawbacks. since the file is created when dragging starts and not when it ends:

1. you could end up with pointless files inside the temp directory, if the user aborts the DND operation
2. if the message being dragged is large, the user could experience some lag